# DataTable in C# - how to find the length of each column with a different number of rows?

Tags: c#, .net, database, ms-access, datatable

I have a DataTable object, LocalDataTable, which contains about 23 different columns, because I'm filling it with 6 different tables from an Access database.

Each Access table has a different number of rows. Therefore, each set of columns in my LocalDataTable has a different number of rows (on average: 4 - 5 columns have the same number of rows).

What I need, is the number of rows, but for each column/column set individually.

I know how to get the number of rows of the entire DataTable:

```
DataRow[] rows;
rows = LocalDataTable.Select();
int numberOfRecords = rows.Length;
```

but how can I get the size of the columns individually? I was thinking to use:

```
rows = LocalDataTable.Select("filter Expression");
```

But this filter works only for rows (it doesn't filter column names) - which doesn't help me.

Any ideas on how to retrieve the length of the respective column? Much obliged

Comment: Suggestion: To help you get the right people to see this question, you may want to use more relevant tags. The three tags you are currently using (`database`, `datatable`, `multiple-columns`) are all generic, or ambiguous, or both. You can hover your mouse over each tag, to see what I mean. What technologies are you actually using? Use those tags in your question. The relevant technology experts will be more likely to see your question, that way.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, I tried. I changed it a little bit but those are basically the technologies I'm using, especially datatable is the class my data is in.

Comment: Your question contains some lines of code. What language are those lines of code written in? Add that tag, as well.

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot the language - it's C#.

Comment: Sounds like need to do an aggregate Count on each column/field. Do these tables have relationships?

Comment: How would that aggregate Count work? No, there are not any relationships between the columns.